# Crear Objeto mediante el valor de una variable Java

Tags: java, poo, java-8, objeto

Necesito ayuda necesito saber si Java permite crear un objeto dinamicamente, mediante el valor de una variable.

***Ejemplo***

```
//Tengo 2 clases:

    public class Auditoria {
    private Long idAuditoria
    //constructores, get y set
    }
    
    publica class Ejemplo {
    private Long idEjemplo
   //constructores, get y set
    }
-------------------------------------------------------
//creo objeto de clase Auditoria y Ejemplo
Auditoria objAuditoria =new Auditoria();
Ejemplo objEjemplo  =new Ejemplo ();
```

*mi pregunta es la siguiente se puede crear un objeto ya sea de tipo Auditoria o ejemplo mediante el valor de una variable como trato de hacer en el siguiente ejemplo.*
***Ejemplo:***

```
String nombreClase ="Auditoria";  // variable que contiene la clase del Objeto a crear
nombreClase objetoAuditoria = new NombreClase(); //utilizo la variable nombreclase para crear el objeto deseado
```

Claramente me da error al tratar de crear el objeto de esa manera, mi pregunta es se puede crear un objeto dinámicamente o alguna otro opción para tratar de lograr lo que necesito.
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `forName` Por lo tanto tu código quedaría como:

`Class class = Class.forName(nombreClase);`